# Roxygen error "Skipping invalid path"

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen2

The output from running devtools::document(). I have no idea how to fix this and the roxygen documentation is not great at helping figure error messages out. Any ideas on how to get rid of this so my functions can be documented?

```
Updating NEONExclusionZones documentation
Loading NEONExclusionZones
First time using roxygen2 4.0. Upgrading automatically...
Writing NAMESPACE
Skipping invalid path:  1CalcMosqImpact-TITLE.Rd 
Skipping invalid path:  1IstotopicChange-TITLE.Rd 
Skipping invalid path:  1findInters-TITLE.Rd 
Skipping invalid path:  1rad_foot-TITLE.Rd
```

Here is an example of one of the functions I am trying to document. I realize its not fully documented, but I am trying to get a basic package working that I can continue to update.

```
##'NAME 
#'@name 1findInters
#'
##'TITLE 
#'@title Find intersection between footprint curve and a threshold curve
#'
##'TYPE 
#'Standalone R Function
#'
##'DESCRIPTION
#'@description Calculates where the flux footprint curve and the threshold curve intersect. 
#'
##'USAGE 
#'\dontrun{
#'  find_inters(fun_weight=impact_KM01[x,], location=x_step_airs[-1], threshold=SA_dist)
#'  }
#'  
##'ARGUMENTS 
#' @param fun_weight List of footprint curve distances
#' @param location List of distance from tower [m]
#' @param threshold Threshold for influence of all activities on tower measurement source areas [%]
#' 
##'DETAILS
#' 
#'
##'VALUE 
#'
#'
##'NOTE 
#'
##'SEE ALSO
#'
#'
#'
#'
##'EXAMPLES 
#
#'

find_inters <-  function(
  fun_weight,
  location,
  threshold
) {

  #difference between footprint curve and threshold line
  DIFF <- fun_weight - threshold

  #interpolate to ensure finding local result
  location1 <- approx(location, n=1e3)$y
  DIFF1 <- approx(x=location, y=DIFF, xout=location1)$y      

  #find intersect farthest away from tower 
  #in order to find 1 real zero crossing, at least two zero crossings have to be present. 
  #Hence I added c(-1,1) here
  WHR <- extrema(c(-Inf,Inf,DIFF1))
  if(WHR$ncross <= 1) {
    out <- NA
  } else {
    #As I added c(-1,1) above, two indices have to be subtracted again here.
    out <- round( location1[WHR$cross[WHR$ncross,2]-2] )
  }
  #return result
  return(out)

}
```

Comment: you should follow the format and examples in the roxygen description, vignettes, other packages, etc https://github.com/yihui/roxygen2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you have filenames that being with a number rather than a letter. The [relevant code is here that produces the message is here](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/blob/009ae8bdac7580db23e6ad00c98cd65ee4375fe6/R/utils.R#L103-L112). And I believe @rawr's comment is correct: you're using malformatted Roxygen syntax, which is the ultimate cause of the problem.

Comment: That fixed it. I didn't read anything about names not being able to start with numbers, but good to know. Thank you!