# How to export functions starting not whith a letter using roxygen?

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen, infix-operator

I have a follow up question on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879349/are-binary-operators-infix-functions-in-r-generic-and-how-to-make-use-of). Suppose I want an own `+` function for my class `expo`. On my normal R session the following works perfectly

```
'+.expo' <- function(a, b) a ^ b
r <- 2; class(r) <- "expo"
s <- 3; class(s) <- "expo"
r + s # gives 8
```

But running `devtools::document()` gives me the `Skipping invalid path:  .expo.Rd` message. If I understand [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739011/roxygen-error-skipping-invalid-path) correctly, `'+.expo'` is an invalid name for a function as each function has to start with a (small or capital) letter. Now I wonder how can `ggplot2` provide a function `'+.gg'`? And more importantly: how can my package provide a class-specific `+` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R` allows functions to start with something else then a letter, but `roxygen` per default does not. But you can use the argument `@rdname` to give such functions an alternative name used in the documentation. So, your `.R`-file might look like

```
#' @param a first object
#' @param b second object
#' @return exponential result
#' @export
#' @rdname expo-add
'+.expo' <- function(a, b) a ^ b
```

The `.R`-File to the mentioned `ggplot2` function `'+.gg'` can be found [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/plot-construction.r).